# Interacting Window Components from Member Object

Tags: c++, qt, coding-style

As Qt programs happen to live within their MainWindow class, I am having troubles altering the design components via a member class, that, because of inter-inclusion of headers leading to compilation errors.

`MainWindow` class holding a `EventManager` member object needs to have its design components modified in a method of `EventManager` without having multi-inclusion issue, that considering that `MainWindow` needs to include `EventManager` to be able to hold it within its class as member.

What would be the best (programmatically speaking) method to achieve this goal ?

Comment: To avoid cyclic inclusion you might consider using forward declaration for your `EventManager` class in `MainWindow` header.

Comment: This is effectively something that I've considered, however I've been told that forward declarations often result from bad design which led me to seek a potentially better way of doing it.

Comment: multi-inclusion issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832018/multiple-inclusion-of-header-file-c

Comment: and cyclic inclusion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes